# Android emulator ignores settings in system/etc/hosts file

Tags: android, emulation, hosts

***What I did***. To work with testing api I need to add specific ip and host name into ***hosts*** file. So I edited config on my pc ***system/etc/hosts***. After that I could use my host on PC browser.

PC hosts file img:
[image]
_

Then I tried to open same host on Android Studio Emulator (same PC). And the browser shows error "webpage not available ... ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". Strange, because, I assumed the emulator would use PC OS hosts properties (like on Mac with X-Code emulator).

Emulator error in browser img:
[image]
_

So I rooted emulator, changed it hosts file same way as on PC and rebooted emulator - the same error in browser.

Emulator hosts file img:
[image]
_

It seems like Android Emulator ignores both PC hosts file settings and its own.
How to make emulator work with my host ip-hostname pair? Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sysadmin somehow resolved this situation on his side. So now I use the [-dns-server  option](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) to manually specify the addresses of DNS servers. And my testing api requests work.

```
emulator -avd nexuss5 -dns-server xxx.xx.x.x
```

Answer (score 3):

The last line in the devices `hosts` file must terminate with a new line.

Comment: lol:) Are you kidding me :) It worked really. Thank you so much.

Comment: I spent a few hours trying to figure this out finally. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Emulator doc this is intended behavior:

> Note that this usually means that the emulator ignores the content of your "hosts" file (/etc/hosts on Linux/OS X, %WINDOWS%/system32/HOSTS on Windows).

You, however, can access your host machine from inside the emulator with 10.0.2.2 (instead of testing in your example)

Comment: How exacly should I specify 10.0.2.2 inside emulator? In my hosts file, in URL (instead of my "testing" host name) or start somehow emulator specifying it? (unfortunately those options didn't work for me)

Comment: Inside the url, so instead of `http://testing` using `http://10.0.2.2` should work. Your url to be tested is accessible from your host machine? That url `http://this.is.my.machine/webservice` needs to be replaced by `http://10.0.2.2/webservice`